# Join data frames after applying fuzzywuzzy library

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy, fuzzy

I have two data frames

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Key':['Apple Souce', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Strawberry', 'John tabel']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Key2':['Aple suce','apple','app','orange', 'Mango', 'Orag','Jon table', 'Straw', 'Bannanna', 'Berry'],'Key23':['1', '2', '2','3', '3','4','4', '5', '6', '7']})
```

I am using fuzzywuzzy to match the strings

```
def fuzzy_merge(df_1, df_2, key1, key2, threshold=85):

    s = df_2[key2].tolist()

    m = df_1[key1].apply(lambda x: process.extract(x, s))    
    df_1['matches'] = m

    m2 = df_1['matches'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join([i[0] for i in x if i[1] >= threshold]))
    df_1['matches'] = m2
    df_1 = df_1.assign(matches=df_1.matches.str.split(',')).explode('matches')
    

    return df_1

df = fuzzy_merge(df1, df2, 'Key', 'Key2', threshold=85)
```

and then merging the data frames

```
merge = pd.merge(df, df2, left_on=['matches'],right_on=['Key2'],how='outer').fillna(0)
```

The result I am getting is

[image]

whereas the result I want is

```
Key            matches     key2          key23
Apple souce    Aple suce   Aple suce      1
Apple souce    apple       apple          2
Apple souce    app         app            2
Banana         Bannanna   Bannanna        6
Orange         orange     orange          3
Strawberry     Straw      Straw           5
Strawberry     Berry      Berry           7
John tabel                0               0
0              0          Jon table       4
```

not sure which join condition is giving the wrong results and why does apple is not matching apple in join

Comment: Part of the problem is that you are doing `', '.join(...)` with a space after the comma but you are only splitting on `.str.split(',')` without the space after the comma so your strings become `' apple'` which wont match with `'apple'`

Comment: This was such a stupid mistake. Thank you for the help, it works now!